# Configure/Change Windows DNS Server Port

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2008, bind, configure

How do you configure/change Windows DNS Server Port? I would like to change the port? I've done it with BIND(http://www.golinuxhub.com/2012/08/change-port-no-for-dns-server.html), but cannot find how to do this with Windows DNS Server? For some reason when I google "Configure Windows DNS Server Port", I find nothing. Does a DNS Server for Windows Server, have to be port 53? If so why can you not change it?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe its possible with Microsoft DNS.

An alternative might be to port forward the desired port to 53.

Something like `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=#### listenaddress=1.2.3.4 connectport=53 connectaddress=1.2.3.4` would work if the DNS protocol was only using TCP, but since DNS queries are usually made using the UDP protocol, this wouldn't work.  So, you'd have to find something that can forward UDP packets too.

You might try [Simple UDP Proxy/Pipe 0.4.1](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/Simple-UDP-Proxy-Pipe.shtml) for example.